# Function after fadeout+remove(table row) won't work?

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I added fadeout+remove from this code [jquery table rows line totals and grand total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324928/jquery-table-rows-line-totals-and-grand-total) ,but the `UpdateTotals(this)`'s stop working.Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much

```
$('body').delegate('.delete', 'click', function() {          
//$(this).parents('tr').remove(); // UpdateTotals works fine
$(this).parents('tr').fadeOut('normal', function() { $(this).remove()}); //UpdateTotals won't work
UpdateTotals(this);
});
```

Comment: Try putting `UpdateTotals` before the fadeout

Comment: Side note: Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) rather than `.delegate()`.  `$('body').on('click', '.delete', function() {})`